# ImportError: No module named scipy.sparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, importerror

I installed Scipy on Ubuntu using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
pip install scipy
```

but when run import, I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named scipy.sparse
```

I searched and tried the following and reinstalled Scipy:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-scipy
```

but still got the same error.

Update: I didn't import scipy in my python file, just imported keras.

Here is the error message:

```
(my_env)  ..  $ python test.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    import keras
  File "/home/ ../my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/ ../my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
  File "/home/ ../my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/multi_gpu_utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..layers.merge import concatenate
  File "/home/ ../my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..engine.base_layer import Layer
  File "/home/ ../my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .training import Model
  File "/home/ ../my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import training_arrays
  File "/home/../my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse import issparse
ImportError: No module named 'scipy.sparse'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213551/installing-scipy-with-pip You need libatlas-base-dev gfortran

Comment: Show us your import line, the full error traceback and your projects file structure.

Comment: @BalázsNagyillés Tried it now and the same error

Comment: @KlausD. the question  is updated

Comment: We really prefer text over screenshots here on SO.

Comment: @KlausD. ok, updated!

Comment: You missed the file structure. Is there anything called `scipy` in your folder?

Comment: no scipy in the folder

Answer (score 5):

scipy path mixed up. 
Uninstall

```
pip uninstall scipy
```

Install using conda worked for me

```
conda install scipy
```

Comment: you can also use `conda install -c conda-forge scipy`

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later you could install Scipy and Keras for Python 3 with `sudo apt install python3-scipy python3-keras` and you'd be good to go, however you are using Ubuntu 16.04 and you installed Scipy for Python 2 which is not compatible with TensorFlow for Python 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6, so install the default Scipy package for Python 3 instead with this command:

```
sudo apt install python3-scipy
```

For further instructions on installing TensorFlow in Ubuntu read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54971370/installing-tensorflow-on-raspbian-stretch-2019-11-13-has-python-compatibility-pr/54976338#54976338). It's worth reading because you are going to have to check for package version compatibility when working with TensorFlow from now on.

The command `pip install scipy` is not correct either if the purpose of that command was to upgrade Scipy. The correct command to upgrade Scipy would have been `pip install --upgrade --user scipy` and even so it would have been useless because your scipy that is currently installed is only for Python 2 and your TensorFlow is for Python 3.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade --user scipy` solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 3, but with pip you install scipy for Python 2.
Use:

```
pip3 install scipy
```

or:

```
sudo apt install python3-scipy
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pip3 install scipy
```

and to install pip3

```
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure on which Python version you've installed Scipy try in the terminal:

```
which Python
```

Then try:

```
pip freeze
```

to get a list of all the installed packages.

Maybe you have more than one python version and have installed the package to one and trying to execute your code using the other.

Comment: Then I think your Scipy install went wrong. Try to uninstall and install the wheel file this time: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Comment: nothing appeared when execute which python .. but with python -- version .. pythn3.5.2 and from pip freeze scipy==1.2.1 is shown

Comment: Did you try to install it through wheel file?

Comment: I also do recommend to try installing Anaconda distribution . It would save plenty of time of installing packages and that type of issues.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
```

Note the `3` in `python`, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to the latest version:

```
pip install --upgrade scipy
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Install it with pip instead, run:

```
pip install scipy
```

That did the trick for me, hope it helps!

EDIT: Forgot you're using python 3.x, run this instead:

```
pip3 install scipy
```